# Multiple models query and sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm wondering how to join up two different models, and then sort them by via another associated model.

Say I've got an ACCOUNT, that has_many CARS and BIKES, and they both have a polymorphic relation (has_one) to a WHEELSET.

How would I write a query to select all bikes and cars for a given account, and have them sorted by the wheelset (or another column in the wheelset model?)

```
Account
has_many :cars, :bikes

Bike
belongs_to :account
has_one wheelset, :as => wheelable

Car
belongs_to :account
has_one wheelset, :as => wheelable

Wheelset
belongs_to :wheelable, :polymorphic => true
```

I'm thinking something like the following, (which doesn't work unfortunately)

```
a = Account.first
sets = a.bikes.includes(:wheelset) + self.cars.includes(:wheelset)
sets.order('wheelset.wheels ASC')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build an standard Ruby array and use the array [sort method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) to order them.

```
a = Account.first
sets = Array.new
sets += a.bikes + a.cars
sets.sort! { |a, b| a.wheelable <==> b.wheelable }
```

I havent tested this but its roughly how I would go about it given this situation.

Comment: Correct. Was on a tiny netbook. Could barely read the screen :D /excuse